# How do I test if wide characters work in my app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I tried this:

```
std::wcout << L"\u20AC" << L"\n";
```

But it only prints the newline. Am I not doing it right?

I have a function that takes const wchar_t* and I tried passing L"\u20AC" to it and it crashes at the part where I do wctombs_s on it. I think it's getting a NULL instead of the widechar.

Comment: Post the code.  Adding C++ tag to this to increase audience.

Comment: The code is the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350259/how-do-i-send-wide-characters-using-winsocks-send-function

But if I try sending L"\u20AC" to this function, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

L"\u20AC" is not a character, it is a string of wide characters. If you want print a single wide character to the console, you should write `std::wcout << '\u20AC' << L"\n";`
But if you want to print a string of wide chars then `std::wcout << L"\\u20AC"<< L"\n";`